# Accessing iframe injected by chrome extension using JQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension, sizzle

Hi I am creating a chrome extension in which I am injecting iframe into some pages. In the iframe's onload function I am trying to access elements inside iframe using Jquery.

```
$("#divInside-iframe",iframeDocument)
```

While trying to do so I get an error:

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.whateverpage.com" from accessing a frame with origin "chrome-extension://meehnkofmafeb******".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match.

Interesting thing is, this error happens the first time I try to access something inside iframe. It will not happen in subsequent calls unless, I access something from regular page dom in between. After which the error repeats itself one time again.

Something as funny as

```
try{
    $("#divInside-iframe",iframeDocument)
}catch(error){
    $("#divInside-iframe",iframeDocument)
}
```

works as a way around!

Also note error is in the sizzle part of Jquery code.

Checked with Jquery 2.1.3 and 1.11.1

Answer (score 0):

Well It depends on the Content you are loading in iFrame.  If you are loading the content from the same host then it can be done as follow

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>contents demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="//api.jquery.com/" width="80%" height="600" id="frameDemo"></iframe>

<script>
$( "#frameDemo" ).contents().find( "a" ).css( "background-color", "#BADA55" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i am not sure about if the content loaded is from third party website. I hope this would help you

Comment: I am loading extension's content. Something like [`(myiFrame.src = chrome.extension.getURL('/pages/index.html')`];